# How to change max listeners from 32 to unlimited

Tags: shoutcast

i installed shout cast on Ubuntu server .
First: i want to know how to change maximum number of listeners from 32 to unlimited.
Second : there is any app to stream to server from ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Its impossible to set the amount of listeners to "Unlimited" but you can change it to whatever number you want to.

You can do this by going to your `sc_serv.conf` or whatever you named your config file and then editing the file and finding `MaxUser=32` and change the number to whatever you want to.

If you need help setting up let me know by emailing me (lsmithx2 "@" fragfm.org.uk)